# Display all DB data in JSON format while URL is selected using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I need one help.I need to return all Database value in JSON format when any URL is selected using Angular.js and PHP. Suppose somebody selected this url('http://abcd.com/#/product/deal/catagory') in any mobile app.So it should return all required data to that mobile app.I am explaining my controller side code for the required data.

```
$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/category.php?op=disp",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    });
```

Here `response.data` is containing all db value which should return.I need here when any user will select the given URL how these data will pass to that user.Please help me.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to filter the data, or how to display the data in the view?

Comment: @Tristan : Actually i need to make URL for Mobile app.When that url will touched from mobile side the respective data will return.